# Gulp-nodemon's watch w/ tasks isn't working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, nodemon

I have the following task that I'm trying to use for development.  I have two other tasks than I need run before gulp-nodemon starts and restarts my server process.

It STARTS just fine, but upon discovering a change in my /src file tree, the two tasks are run, but the node process never restarts and I never see my .on('restart') message fire.  It then just hangs after the two other tasks complete (I get Gulp "Finished..." messages for both of them).  Am I missing something here?

```
import gulp from 'gulp'
import nodemon from 'gulp-nodemon'

gulp('watch', ['copy-assets', 'transpile'], () => {
  return nodemon({
    execMap: {
      js: `node`
    },
    script: `build/index.js`,
    watch: `src/**/*.js`,
    ext: `js`,
    tasks: ['copy-assets', 'transpile']
  }).on(`restart`, () => {
    console.log(`App restarted!`)
  })
})
```

Comment: Did you forgot a back quote at the end of the `watch` line or your code is really like that? Because it could be the reason of your problems.

Comment: Nah.. that's a typo.. it's not a syntax problem.. code compiles and runs just fine.. nodemon just isn't restarting the actual process.  Thanks for the catch